# EditText not Losing focus on Back Button Press with Scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I've overridden onBackPressed() in my activity like so:
*activity starts with the soft keyboard up, but when the back button is pressed, thereby closing the soft keyboard, the edittext doesn't lose focus, so knowing this, I decided to force the edittext to lose focus manually when the keyboard is closed by pressing the back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();
}
```

The problem is that the edittext still doesn't lose focus; even though the root view in my layout has the attributes `focusable="true"` and `focusableInTouchMode="true"` which seems to be the work around for making sure an edittext doesn't refocus accidentally.

Any idea why my edittext isn't losing focus?
*it does lose focus whenever another edittext gains focus

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.example.android.views.CounterEditText
                android:id="@+id/item_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                custom:maxCharacters="@integer/maxCharactersInTitle">
            </com.example.android.views.CounterEditText>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/attributes_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/item_title"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.example.android.views.CounterEditText
                    android:id="@+id/attribute_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    custom:maxCharacters="@integer/maxCharactersInAttribute">
                </com.example.android.views.CounterEditText>

                <com.example.android.views.CounterEditText
                    android:id="@+id/attribute_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    custom:maxCharacters="@integer/maxCharactersInAttribute">
                <com.example.android.views.CounterEditText>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_attribute_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/attribute_container"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/item_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/genericGrayBgColor"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="@string/item_description_hint"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_item_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/create_item_button_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Update:

The problem isn't that `getCurrentFocus().clearFocus()` isn't working. The problem is that, when the soft keyboard is up and the back button is pressed, `onBackPressed()` isn't called.

Comment: You are facing problem because there is a scrollview in your hierarchy. Check solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100831/stop-scrollview-from-setting-focus-on-edittext). These should work.

Comment: @NightFury check update. are you saying that the reason `onBackPressed` isn't being called is because of the `ScrollView`?